# PayPal, Authorize.net, and other payment gateways and PSPs

Tags: payment, paypal, payment-gateway, authorize.net, payment-methods

I have a generic question concerning processing payments with Magento.

1. First of all, what is the difference between the PayPal Website Payment
   Standard option available in Europe and the PayPal Payment Standard
   option available in the USA?
2. Also, some European countries also display a separate Paypal Express Checkout
   option. Is this option mutually exclusive with PayPal Website Payment Standard?
   That is, do I need to configure either one or the other. Is it advantageous or
   even possible to configure both options?

A. PayPal Payment Standard:
   Accept credit card and PayPal payments securely.

B. PayPal Website Payment Standard:
   Accept credit card and PayPal payments securely.

C. PayPal Express Checkout:
   Add PayPal as an additional payment method to your checkout page.

It seems to me that A and B are really the same thing, just offered
in different locations around the globe under a different name, and
that if I choose option B then this is equivalent to option C plus
I can also process credit cards, so B is more advantageour than C
and if I go with option B then I do not need option C. Is this correct?

1. This may sound like a stupid question, but if I go with PayPal then
   do I still need to go through a PSP (Payment Service Provider)?
   Presumably PayPal cannot act as a PSP and so I need one to
   enable transactions between my online store and Paypal?
   What is the difference between a payment gateway and a PSP?
2. I'm tempted to go with Authorize.net as the PSP, just because it is
   available by default and should thus be proven, tested, and stable,
   unlike some other extensions which might be buggy, especially now
   that a new release of Magento has been published. Or are the other
   Magento PSP extensions equally viable alternatives? How do these
   compare in terms of pricing and availability. Is Authorize.net
   available globally, or is it just available, say, in the US?

Thanks for answering my questions.

I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal Payments Standard is just another way to integrate with Paypal, basically Express Checkout is more advanced way to integrate. See the difference here: https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_additional-payment-ref-impl1

Answering your question on credit card acceptance: Express Checkout also allow to accept credit cards in the same way as Standard. Read more about it here: https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/express-checkout